# Firebase query implementation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If we query data from Firebase on a key for a child node, does it downloads the whole child node and filter data in the application or it downloads the query specific data? i.e. the filtered data

```
String myUserId = getUid();
Query myTopPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("user-posts").child(myUserId).orderByChild("starCount");
myTopPostsQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {});
```

`myTopPostsQuery` will sort data according to `starCount` and I will receive data in the `addChildEventListener()` I want to know that whether this data is being filtered inside my app after receiving or my app downloads only the filtered data from the Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a filter in your query you will download the query specific data without any operation executed on the client side.
Keep in mind that:

> - You can only use one order-by method at a time. Calling an order-by method multiple times in the same query throws an error.
> - You can combine multiple limit or range functions. For example, you can combine the startAt() and endAt() methods to limit the results to a specified range of values.

For any other info take a read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)

Answer (score 1):

You get the data already filtered. When you use a query, let say, `limitToLast(10)` you get only those 10 elements. This is happening also in your case with `orderByChild("starCount")`. In your `SnanpShot` will find only those filtered elements. Please visit [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) for more details.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you pasted here, your query will just retrieve all the posts for the database path `user-posts/<id>` with an ordered manner which means that there is not filter. But still you will get back all the available posts under the path you are querying. It can be a "semi-filter" as it will find only the posts which include `starCount` field

The best thing is to filter during your query in order to retrieve back exactly what is needed and not everything as you are doing right now, imagine that this list of posts can be really big so you will have a big issue with performance later.

Read the following section here about sorting & filtering.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#orderbychild

Apart from that consider to add an index in `userId` field for speeding up your query.